# Triac circuit resistor tied to motor

Tags: motor-controller, triac

I've run across a triac circuit which has a huge 510 ohm 50W load resistor tied to a 115V 1.6A PSC fan motor. I'm not quite sure what that big resistor is for. Ideas?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa6xIC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Do you mean 1.6W or 1.6**k**W?  Please edit the question if it's in error, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I need new glasses. Of course it's 1.6A rather than W.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that it's designed for a fan speed control with a minimum speed.  When the triac is off, the circuit is completed by the resistor, the motor sees reduced current, and turns at lower speed (with lots of slip).  When the triac is on, the motor goes fast.

Presumably the PSC motor is designed for this sort of service -- I suspect that some randomly-chosen induction motor would likely overheat.

Comment: "Presumably the PSC motor is designed for this sort of service...." More specifically -- designed for one specific fan. The system may not work well for another fan.